# Como Inibir exibição de informação no console do eclipse usando hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, log

Gostaria de uma ajuda. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando jpa-hibernate, jsf e primefaces. Sempre que rodo a aplicação aparece o seguinte no console:

```
0 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.3.0.GA
46 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.2.5
62 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
62 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : cglib
78 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
187 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.3.1.GA
498 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: nome da classe
```

aqui exibe todas as classes mapeadas
.
.
.

```
6250 [http-8080-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - schema update complete
```

Como inibir a exibição dessas informações no console?

Obrigda por qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Se for apenas no Eclipse e tiver o arquivo `persistence.xml` procure por esta linha

```xml
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
```

E mude de `ALL` para `FATAL` ou alguma flag com menos logging que todos (`INFO`,`CONFIG`.`ERROR`,`WARN`).

## log4j - logging "comum"

**Mudando no arquivo de configuração**

- Texto Simples

  ```
  log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
  ```
- Arquivo XML

```xml
     <logger name="org.hibernate">
           <level value="info"/> 
     </logger>
```

## log4j - logging SQL

- Arquivo de Configuração

  Exclua esta linha **se existir**:

  log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
- Por meio de programação:

```java
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure().
    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
```

Recomendo que veja também o [manual do log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: Obrigada Kyllopardiun
pesquisei mais so o log4j e descobri outras possiblidades.

Comment: Olá user, você pode agradecer a um usuário que deu uma resposta útil através de um voto positivo. Caso a resposta do usuário esteja correta você também aceitá-la. Caso tenho resolvido seu problema de alguma maneira diferente também pode contribuir com a comunidade postando sua própria resposta e aceitando-a.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando [a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25028/100) do colega [Kyllopardiun](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8917/kyllopardiun), segue uma tradução livre da tabela categorias de log específicas do Hibernate:

> - `org.hibernate.SQL` → Loga todos os comandos DML SQL conforme eles são executados
> - `org.hibernate.type` → Loga todos os parâmetros JDBC
> - `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl` → Loga todos os comandos DDL SQL conforme eles são executados
> - `org.hibernate.pretty` → Loga o estado de todas as entidades (máximo de 20 entidades) associadas à sessão no momento do *flush*
> - `org.hibernate.cache` → Loga toda atividade de cache de segundo nível
> - `org.hibernate.transaction` → Loga atividades relacionadas com transações
> - `org.hibernate.jdbc` → Loga todas as aquisições de recursos JDBC
> - `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.AST` → Logas [ASAs](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_sint%C3%A1tica_abstrata)
>     do HQL e SQL durante o *parsing* das consultas
> - `org.hibernate.secure` → Logos todos os pedidos de autorização JAAS
> - `org.hibernate` → Loga Tudo. Isso é um monte de informação, mas é útil para *troubleshooting*.

**Fonte**: [Hibernate 4.3 Manual - Configuration - Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-logging)

---

### Para desativar todos os logs:

#### Formato XML

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="OFF" />
</logger>
```

#### Formato properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF
```